# Showing operator norm over $\mathbb{R}$ attains supremum

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, operator-theory

Let $V, W$ be finite dimensional normed vector spaces over the real numbers. Define the operator norm on the vector space of linear maps $L(V,W)$ as $||A|| := \sup \{ ||Av|| \mid v \in V, ||v||=1 \}$.

I'm trying to show that there exists a vector $v \in V$ with $||v||=1$ such that $||A||=||Av||$, and I would like to check if my solutions works.

Let $S:= \{ v \in V \mid ||v||=1 \}$. Then this is a compact set; indeed, pick a basis of $V$ and define a norm on $V$ such that we get an isometry $f$ between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ (why can we do this?). The map $f$ is continuous, and it sends the usual sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is compact to $S$. Since the image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact, $S$ is compact.

Finally, a compact set always contains its supremum, so there exists a $v_0 \in V$ such that $||A|| := \sup \{ ||Av|| \mid v \in V, ||v||=1 \} = ||A v_0 ||$, as required.

Comment: What do you mean by "define a norm on $V$"?  The norm on $V$ is already given at the start.

Comment: I suppose we can use the norm given to us at the start, yes? I was following this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659347/if-a-normed-space-is-finite-dimensional-the-unit-sphere-is-compact for the proof of compactness.

Comment: @GreenCoffee248 The proof there is puzzling. You can prove that $S$ is sequentially compact, which is equivalent to its compactness since $V$ is a metric space, with Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: Ok, I guess I can use something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500579/compactness-of-the-unit-sphere-in-finite-dimensional-normed-vector-space ? Given this compactness issue, is the rest of my proof okay?

Comment: "a compact set always contains its supremum" seems odd. Typically sets don't have suprema, functions do. Perhaps rephrase this?

Comment: @JohnHughes: what? "supremum" means *least upper bound*. It's a property of sets, not of functions.

Comment: (I should have said "ordered sets")

Comment: You're completely right, of course. I was thinking "extremum", as in "continuous functions on compact sets attain their extrema," which seemed to me like the theorem that was obviously needed. I should have read (and thought) more carefully.

Comment: “A compact set always contains its supremum” remains incorrect. A normed vector space is rarely an ordered set.

Answer (score 1):

Consider  the following set $S$={$v\in V;||v||=1$}$=B_V[0,1]$ by riesz compactness theorem $S$ is copmact since V is of  *finite dimension* . And then define the  mapping  $N:S\rightarrow\mathbb R^+$ by $N(v)=||Av||$ since $S$ is compact and the  function  $N$ is continous,it's not hard to check that $N$ is continous,  then, $N$ is bounded and attiens it's boundary  **i.e.**  $sup${$N(v); v\in S$} exists ,morover, $\exists v_0\in S$ such that $N(v_0)=$$sup${$N(v); v\in S$}$=$$sup${$N(v); v\in V,||v||=1$} so $\exists v_0 $,such that$||Av_0||=||A||$

Comment: I see that a continuous function $N$ on a compact set attains its maximum, but how do we show that maximum = supremum in this case? I think this is related to what is being discussed in the comments of the original question.

Comment: @GreenCoffee248 let $M=$ {$N(v); v\in V,||v||=1$}  since $s=supM \in M$ then $maxM=supM$ did i answer your question ?

Comment: @GreenCoffee248 another remark if the $max$ of a set exists then it's equal to the $sup$ i.e. $supM=maxM$